# React pages that is made by create-react-app don't work on IE. Isn't babel useful?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, internet-explorer

I am developing a project with staring create-react-app.

somwhow pages that uses materil-ui always become a white blank page on IE.

a part of package.json is here.
Some pages occur error below.but i can't detect any.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.42",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
},
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "es2015"
    ]},
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not ie <= 11",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  }
```

[image]
After
Modifying
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your configuration for `"browserslist": {` in `package.json`?

Comment: Ive added that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your previous discussion, it seems that you are using react-scripts 3.3.1. You could check the package.json file to verify it.

As far as I know, when using react-scripts 3.3.0 and higher version, it might be cause the "SyntaxError". you could check the following issues:

[github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197), [github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195).

As a workaround, you could try to downgrade the react-scripts version. As far as I know, it can still work with `react-scripts@3.2.0`. Besides, please do forget to add [the `react-app-polyfill` polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

You should whitelist IE 11 in the production build, because `"not ie <= 11",` removes the IE support. Because that line indicates do not support IE 11 or earlier(`<=`).

```
 "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
       "ie 11",
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  }
```

to build the end-user version the following command should be used:

```
npm run build
```

More details about [productions builds from the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/).

If that doesn't work a polyfill can be added to `index.html` in `public`:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did  use"react-scripts start"

Comment: You should use `npm run build` and serve the contents of the `build` folder with the end users.

Comment: Thanks . After building and put the project in my remote server. the certain error came out. it implies the project is still using ES2015

Comment: Did you use the contents of the `build` folder?

Comment: Absolutely yes .

Comment: What version of `react-scripts` are you using?

Comment: The project uses "react-scripts": "3.3.1",

Comment: Thenks. I added it in <Head> in index.html in public  However, nothing changed.

Comment: Did you hard-refresh IE?

Comment: And the script tag has successfully loaded in IE?

Comment: How should I check it?

Comment: Inspect element in IE

Comment: I move it to inside Body tag. As far as I can see it , IE loads "cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"